# CSS styles getting removed after page refresh in React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm building a React application and I'm facing an issue with the CSS styles that I'm applying to the `Select` component from material UI. Specifically, when I apply some styles to remove padding from the `Select` component, the padding gets removed. However, when I refresh the page, the padding gets added back.

Here is my code:

```
                      <Select
                        variant="standard"
                        name="status"
                        value={selectedStatus}
                        label="New Status"
                        sx={{
                          overflowY: "auto",
                          height: 30,
                          width: "inherit",
                          backgroundColor: "white !important",
                          marginX: "2rem",
                          overflow: "hidden",
                          textAlign: "left",
                          "& .MuiSelect-select": {
                            padding: "0 !important"
                          }
                        }}
                        onChange={handleStatusChange}
                      >
                        <MenuItem value="1">Active</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem value="0">Inactive</MenuItem>
                      </Select>
```

As you can see, I'm trying to remove the padding from the Select component using the !important modifier to ensure that the styles take precedence over other styles. However, when I refresh the page, the padding gets added back.

Can anyone suggest a solution to this issue? I'm not sure if this is a React-specific problem or if it's related to CSS or Material-UI, which is the UI library I'm using. Please note that I'm using Typescript in my project.

Comment: Please provide a code sandbox reproducing your problem. There shouldn't be any reason to use `!important` here.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it will help , if the cached version of the CSS file has a different font styles than the current version of the CSS file, this could cause the issue,  to fix this we need to add a cache-busting query string to the CSS file URL  add "?v=1" along with your stylesheet name.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css?v=1" />

Comment: Please [edit] to add the info from you comment to the answer itself. You might enjoy the possibilities offered by this info https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help to get as close as possible to [answer].

Answer (score -1):

Use the different SCSS file.

Code in .scss file:

```
.select-new {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 30px;
  width: inherit;
  background-color: #fff !important;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: left;
  .MuiSelect-select {
  padding: 0 !important;
  }
}
```

import the .scss file into your current file & replace sx with `className="select-new"`